# Need to allow user to delete own profile - Rails, Devise, Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, cancan

After several hours of trying to piece together code I've found here and across the web, I think I've gotten to the point where I may have made a mess of my code.  Please let me know if you need any other snippets, I will try to include the pertinent code below.  There are separate models for the user and the profile.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: rake route shows this route:
 admin_destroy_user DELETE   /users/:id(.:format)      profiles#destroy

And I am getting this error when trying to load the edit profile page (localhost:3000/settings/profile):
"No route matches {:controller=>"devise/profiles", :action=>"destroy"}"

**_form.html.haml**

```
.row
  .span6
    .actions
      = f.submit 'Save', class: 'btn-submit'
      = link_to 'Delete Account', admin_destroy_user_path, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'btn-delete'
      = link_to 'Cancel', profile_index_path
```

**profile_controller**

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.destroy

  if @user.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users    
match 'users/:id' => 'devise/registrations#destroy', :via => :delete, :as =>    :admin_destroy_user
match 'users/:id' => 'user#show', as: :user
resources :users
```

**ability.rb**

```
if user.is? :admin
  can :access, :admin #access the admin page
  can :manage, :all #do anything to any model
else
  can :read, :all #read any model
  can [:update, :destroy], Profile, :user_id => user.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ProfileController you destroyed wrong object. The target should be profile, but not user.

So it should be something like this

```
def destroy
  @profile = Profile.find(user_id: params[:id])
  if @profile.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
  else
    render_error_message
  end
end
```

However, I really can't find any points to delete a profile. If the profile is empty, just show it as empty as what StackOverflow shows, which is normal.

Comment: Hi Billy, thanks for your answer.  I have implemented it into my code; however, I can't get the page to load to try it out (see edit above with routing errors).  My employer wants users to be able to delete their account.  If you have a better way of implementing that, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!  I will paste the changes from my code below.  This deletes by the user and their profile (two separate models) when the delete button is clicked.

**_form.html.haml**

```
user_registration_path,
```

**profile_controller**

```
def edit
  @user = current_user
end

def destroy
  @user = current_user
  @profile = current_user.profile
  if @profile.destroy
    @user.destroy
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "User deleted."
  else
    render_error_message
  end
end
```

**ability.rb**

```
  can :manage, User do |u|
    u.id == user.id
  end
```

Comment: David, nice you get it working. It would be fine if that met the requirement.

Comment: For future improvement, I'd suggest 1) route the destroy to user but not profile because what you really need is to destroy the account but not profile. You can use `dependent :destroy` on setting associations. 2) Never really DESTROY things instantly, especially the sensitive information, instead use a soft deletion solution, destroy the record, save its data elsewhere, and fully destroy it after some days say a month.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Billy.  If it's not obvious, I am fairly new to rails development and working on a rather large project that is already live.  I'm grateful for your advice.  :)